# Is there any opensource hardware mobile robot platform?

Tags: ros, hardware, robot, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any opensource hardware mobile robot platform?
Like irobot create2, or Pioneer P3-DX?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239393/is-there-any-opensource-hardware-mobile-robot-platform?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TraiBo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28181/traibo/) on 2017-10-13**:
Hi somebodyus ,
http://www.pibot.org/  fully open source robotic platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What comes to my mind are [Poppy](https://www.poppy-project.org/en/) and [iCub](http://www.icub.org/). They are "mobile" but in a different way. If you are only interested about mobile bases with wheels, I think [Turtlebot 2](http://www.turtlebot.com/) is as close as it gets to open source (open source stops at the software level).

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0